# RewriteRule how to deal with slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to go FROM: `www.myDomain.com/test2/second` TO: `www.myDomain.com/test/first.html`

This is what I put in the .htaccess, and it does not work:

```
RewriteRule test2\/second test\/first.html
```

I try to learn. Can anyone explain how does it work please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute paths in rewrites:

```
RewriteRule ^test2/second /test/first.html [R,L]
```

Comment: I have tested and it does not work: I write in the browser: http://www.example.com/test2/second and it does not go to http://www.example.com/test/first.html

Comment: @Nrc Is rewrite module enabled? Where are you putting the htaccess file?

Comment: Yes, rewrite module is enabled. I put the .htaccess inside the folder test

Comment: Now I see. I should put the rule in the .htaccess of the root. I have some question about your code: it is not necessary to escape slashes? What does [R,L] mean? Where can I find if they are other letters like that?